# Cannot get the value of textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made a html document with a form which contains a textarea.
A extern javascriptfile should read the contents of the text area and send it to a php-file

html:

```
<textarea id="ta"></textarea>
```

javascript:

```
alert( $( "#ta" ).val() );
```

But it returned an empty string?!
I have tried it with .text() and .html(), but it did not work too.

I also tried to set text in the textarea:

```
<textarea id="ta">Hello</textarea>
```

but it only returned "Hello" and whatever I added manually in the webpage declined.
Could it be that the value of the textarea does not get updated when I write into it?

Edit: I just tried to replace the form tag and all fieldset tags with divs and it works! But however I would like to know why it did not worked before

Comment: You'll have to show at what point you're calling that alert. Please make a complete example that shows the problem.

Comment: I think you might be saving the value of the textarea once instead of getting a new value, Try adding this code: `<button onclick = "alert(document.getElementById('ta').value);">Click Me For Value</button>`

Comment: Just as an example... https://jsfiddle.net/vcarvalho/wL7rntqa/

Comment: Please try  alert( $( "textarea#ta" ).val() );

Comment: @Oliver Queen: The button works fine and gives me the write output, but why it did not worked in the function?

Comment: Do you have multiple same `id`s? Or is `textarea` for an editor, like Codemirror?

Comment: @Paul_Pander - can you provide your whole code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$('#ta').on('keypress',function() {
   alert($('#ta').val());
});
```

you must watch keyup , keypress , keydown etc.. methods for getting value of textarea

Comment: But I want to get the value of the textarea when a button is pressed and not when the keyup event is triggered

Comment: replace keyup with keypress

Answer (score 1):

Ok I see, in your Html you have your 
`<textarea id="ta"></textarea>` its ok, leave it there.

so if you want to get values from this `<textarea id="ta"></textarea>` you'll need content inside of it, and you will get this content from the user. So basically You need an event to make this happen, in this case, im assuming that you have a button that will trigger this event, and send this info to a PHP file, what you can do is the following:

on the button that will send the info....

**Html:**

`<button id="someButton">Send info</button>`

**JS:**

`$( '#someButton' ).on( 'click', function() {
      var txtValue = $( '#ta' ).val();
      alert( txtValue );
});`

The variable that i created is optional, you can pass **alert( $( '#ta' ).val() );** directly.